# Multilanguage site in Joomla, specific page not loading modules

Tags: joomla, sef

I've got a site built in Joomla, and it is using Joom!Fish for translating articles, which seems to work great.

However there's one page on my site, which in just one of the four languages currently active does not load two of my modules.
I've nailed this down to a SEF-urls problem, de-activating it in Joomla-admin fixes the issue, but I need to have SEF-urls.

Why is the SEF-url working on 3 of my languages, but on the fourth it seems to ignore the itemid parameter and not load my modules.

Using Joomla 1.5x, for SEF-urls I'm using the built-in solution, will perhaps using a SEF-plugin solve this?

Best Regards // Ninja

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by recreating articles menus, modules etc. That was connected to the broken page, and it started working. However it's prolly just a matter of time before the same problem will occur on a new page.

Seems to be an issue with SEF-urls and modules not really supporting it fully. JoomFish seems fairly bad at this.

So if someone else runs into this problem, try recreating everything thats connected to the problem, and hope nothing else will break.